# Consider the statement and decide which of the following implies that this statement is true.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

Consider the statement:

If Bill takes Sam to the concert, then Sam will take Bill to dinner.

Which of the following implies that this statement is true.

$\\$

a. Sam takes Bill to dinner only if Bill takes Sam to the concert.

___Equivalent to Q-->P, which is true if Q is false and P is true, which would make P-->Q false. So this does not imply the above statement is true.

b. Either Bill doesn't take Sam to the concert or Sam takes Bill to dinner.

___If Bill doesn't take Sam to the concert, then P is false and regardless of Q, P-->Q is true. If Sam takes bill to dinner, then Q is true and regardless of P, P-->Q is true. So this implies the above statement is true.

c. Bill takes Sam to the concert.

___Then P is true. But if Q is F, the statement is false, so this does not imply the above statement is true.

d. Bill takes Sam to the concert and Sam takes Bill to dinner.

___Equivalent to P/\Q, and which does imply the above statement to be true.

e. Bill takes Sam to the concert and Sam doesn't take Bill to dinner.

___Equivalent to P/\~Q, so this does not imply the above statement is true.

f. The concert is canceled.

___Then P is always false, so P-->Q is true regardless of truth value for Q. This statement implies the above to be true.

g. Sam doesn't attend the concert.

___Equivalent to P being false, so P-->Q is true regardless of truth value for Q. This statement implies the above to be true.

$\\$

Can anyone confirm my answers?

Comment: Please clarify what P and Q are.

Comment: Whoops. Let P: Bill takes Sam to the concert, and Q: Sam will take Bill to dinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$% Predefined Typography
 \newcommand{\paren} [1]{\left({#1}\right)}
 \newcommand{\bparen}[1]{\bigg({#1}\bigg)}
 \newcommand{\brace} [1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bbrace}[1]{\bigg\{{#1}\bigg\}}
 \newcommand{\floor} [1]{\left\lfloor{#1}\right\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\bfloor}[1]{\bigg\lfloor{#1}\bigg\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\mag}  [1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}
 \newcommand{\bmag} [1]{\bigg\Vert{#1}\bigg\Vert}
 \newcommand{\abs}  [1]{\left\vert{#1}\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\babs} [1]{\bigg\vert{#1}\bigg\vert}
 %
 \newcommand{\labelt}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\label} [2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 \newcommand{\ulabelt}[2]{\overbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\ulabel} [2]{\overbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 %
 \newcommand{\setcomp}[2]{\left\{~{#1}~~\middle \vert~~ {#2}~\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bsetcomp}[2]{\bigg\{~{#1}~~\bigg \vert~~ {#2}~\bigg\}}
 %
 \newcommand{\iint}[2]{\int {#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\dint}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4}{#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\pred}[2]{\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}{#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\ind} [2]{\frac{{\rm d} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predp}[2]{\frac{\partial}{\partial {#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indp} [2]{\frac{{\partial} {#1}}{\partial {#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predn}[3]{\frac{\rm d}^{#3}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indn} [3]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#3} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}}
 %
 \newcommand{\ii}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\ee}{{\rm e}}
 \newcommand{\exp}[1] { {\rm e}^{\large{#1}} }
 %
 \newcommand{\and} {~\text{and}~}
 \newcommand{\xor} {~\text{xor}~}
 \newcommand{\or} {~\text{or}~}
 \newcommand{\T} {\text{True}}
 \newcommand{\F} {\text{False}}
 %
 \newcommand{\red}  [1]{\color{red}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\blue} [1]{\color{blue}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\green}[1]{\color{green}{#1}}
$

> Consider the statement:
>
> If Bill takes Sam to the concert, then Sam will take Bill to dinner.
>
> Which of the following implies that this statement is true?

Alright.

> a. Sam takes Bill to dinner only if Bill takes Sam to the concert.
>
> ___Equivalent to Q-->P, which is true if Q is false and P is true, which would make P-->Q false. So this does not imply the above statement is true.

Agree.  Or more succinctly, for $Q = \F$ and $P=\T$, $(Q \rightarrow P) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q) = \F \rightarrow \T = \F$

> b. Either Bill doesn't take Sam to the concert or Sam takes Bill to dinner.
>
> ___If Bill doesn't take Sam to the concert, then P is false and regardless of Q, P-->Q is true. If Sam takes bill to dinner, then Q is true and regardless of P, P-->Q is true. So this implies the above statement is true.

$$(\lnot P \xor Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$$

Correct, either case of the condition being true makes the resultant true.

> c. Bill takes Sam to the concert.
>
> ___Then P is true. But if Q is F, the statement is false, so this does not imply the above statement is true.

$$P \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$$

Correct again.  $P \and \lnot Q$ is a counterexample.

> d. Bill takes Sam to the concert and Sam takes Bill to dinner.
>
> ___Equivalent to P/\Q, and which does imply the above statement to be true.

$$(P \and Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$$

Correct again.

> e. Bill takes Sam to the concert and Sam doesn't take Bill to dinner.
>
> ___Equivalent to P/\~Q, so this does not imply the above statement is true.

$$(P \and \lnot Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$$

Correct again.

> f. The concert is canceled.
>
> ___Then P is always false, so P-->Q is true regardless of truth value for Q. This statement implies the above to be true.

$$\lnot P \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$$

Correct.

> g. Sam doesn't attend the concert.
>
> ___Equivalent to P being false, so P-->Q is true regardless of truth value for Q. This statement implies the above to be true.

$$\lnot P \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$$

Correct.

They all seem correct to me.

Comment: Okey doke. I'm self-taught and sometimes have questions but don't have anyone to ask for answers. This helps a lot, so thank you.

Comment: @HarryC.Beaver Then you've come to the right place.  Good luck.  Many people probably avoided answering because they assumed this was homework, if you mention that you are teaching yourself, you might get a larger audience.  Also consider learning Latex to make your questions easier to read.  Just right click on any equations you see and choose "Show Math As" "Tex Commands".